# How to secure a PHP script?

Tags: php, security, ftp

I have got a PHP script. In this script I will be connected to a FTP server, and show a file. What would be the best way to secure this script so can only log in 5 times in 1 hour or something like that?

My script:

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION["ftp_user"] = $_POST["user"];    
$_SESSION["ftp_pass"] = $_POST["pass"];
$ftp_pass = $_POST["pass"];
$ftp_server = "ftp.guusvanwalstijn.nl";

function test()    
{ 
echo "Do whatever i want";
}


// Verbinding maken
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server"); 


// Error die je krijgt als je het wachtwoord verkeerd hebt ingetypt
function error_while_connecting() {
echo "Error while connecting to the server";
echo "<br />Probably the password is wrong or the server is offline";
}

// Inloggen met de gegeven inloggegevens
if (@ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user, $ftp_pass)) {
    test();

} else {
    error_while_connecting();
    print("<br />Debug: " . $_POST["pass"] . "<br />");
    print("<br />Debug: " . $_POST["user"] . "<br />");
}

ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

Comment: You want to secure _this script_ or _the ftp server_?

Comment: No idea, i just want this to be protected, do i need to make a mysql login for this?

Comment: Protect _this_? from what? This is the ftp server's _client_. I don't get it.

Comment: I am trying that you cant log in like 100 times in a hour

Comment: By _login_ you mean to the ftp server? That's the ftp server's job. If you're trying to optimize your script to not make redundant downloads, that's no protection. That's optimization. But you have to come up with some way to respond to _your user_ when you decide you can't login to ftp. Also, what if those 5 logins happen in the first _minute_? Please describe what you are _actually trying to achieve_.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't describe the problem very good I also have a login .html : http://pastebin.com/Bn2EPK6B How can I prevent this login from bruteforce attacks? Like, if you login 5 times wrong you get blocked for X minutes

Comment: That's more like it. But you may want to add this clarification to your question. Not everybody goes through all the comments when reading a question.

Comment: You can add protection at the script level, like @sebapalus suggests, but it would be a good idea to add this protection to your FTP server as well. Stopping brute force attacks is an integral feature of modern FTP servers, as far as I know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a log table (timestamps) to the database or store it in file. Fetch last 5 records from it and check if the oldest one is older than 1 hour. If it is, then you can allow to connect to the database. If not, deny, because the limit has been reached. You can also clear contents of this file/db table periodically to avoid too much growth.